# Hidden optional fields in form design

Tags: forms, gui-design, hidden

On a web-app I'm working on, 
we have many forms inside dropdown menus.

On many of them we have an optional field: Description.
This field has been added for the users that want to work on a more "methodical" or pragmatic way.

Unfortunately a "description" textarea takes precious space, especially in case of our quick forms in the dropdowns.

I was thinking to hide the textarea and to put a (+) button close to the label.
By clicking the (+) the user enables the hidden text area and has the possibility to fill a description.

What UI/UX thoughts do you guys have about it? I think it could help UX and the overall form design.

Some notes:

- Javascript is enabled, and it's a fundamental requisite for the web app.
- 99% of our users does not use mobile devices.

Comment: Could you perhaps add a mockup of the UI you are describing? It is a bit hard to visualize what you are talking about. You can add a mockup directly from the question editing interface, just click the Smileyface.

Answer (score 1):

In my organization we us jQuery to bind a simple function to slide down/display a hidden div that contains the other inputs/content. Based on a specific radio/checkbox/dropdown list value selection the function executes. We also style the div so the contents appear to be indented to provide the context that its a sub-question. See example below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree more information would help.  Sometimes you want to encourage users to fill-out the optional description, but the opposite may be true too.  It would also be helpful to know what typical questions and dropdown values are.

I think here are two basic approaches, but in either case, I would definitely use self-adjusting input field that grows in height as you type.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe6F81.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could go with an **automatically expanding textbox** for the description. It would keep the fields rather unobtrusive when not used.

There is a good article/example here:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/expanding-text-areas-made-elegant/

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Owjn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>